# Variables use in conditional part of for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax

I am trying to solve [two sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) in leetcode. My initial solution was:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int lnght = nums.length;
        int i,j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < lngth -1; i++) {
           for (j = 1; j < lngth; j++) {
               if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                   int[] result = {i,j};
                   return result;
               }
           }
        }
    }    
}
```

But this returned a could not find "lngth" variable error as shown:

```
Main.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        for (i = 0; i < lngth -1; i++) {
                        ^
symbol:   variable lngth
location: class Solution
Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
           for (j = 1; j < lngth; j++) {
                           ^
symbol:   variable lngth
location: class Solution
 2 errors
```

I managed to find a workaround by replacing lnght with nums.length in the for loop. Why did this work and not my oroginal implementation?

Also, just replacing the variable did not work. I had to add a return statement after the for loops as follows:

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int lnght = nums.length;
    int i,j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length -1; i++) {
       for (j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
           if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
               int[] result = {i,j};
               return result;
           }
       }
    }
    int[] result = {i,j};
    return result;
}    
}
```

Why did this work and directly returning from inside the if statement not work?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `lngth` != `lnght`. Look at the last 2 letters of both. Question should be closed because this is a simple typo

Comment: My bad. I would appreciate an answer for the second part of the question regarding the return statement.

Comment: That's simple: There is no guarantee that your loop will run at all. (Someone could pass an empty array into the method after all) So if you only have a return statement inside your loop(s) the compiler throws an error because in the case the loop does not run at all the method is never hitting a return statement.

Comment: Please write up your typo find and the return issue as an answer, @OHGODSPIDERS so that the question can rest in peace without kind users popping in looking to provide an answer to an unanswered question.